# Signing PDF with TimeStamp and OCSP using SmartCard

Tags: pdf, itext, smartcard, sign, ocsp

I need to sign PDF with TimeStamp and OCSP using SmartCard.
Any example how to this with ITextSharp !?

Comment: Sorry outsider, voting to close. Directly asking us for code for a specific programming problem is not how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @owlstead One of the best ways to learn and solve problems is by reading other people's examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on how to do this is under development: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures20120902.pdf
The first version of the documentation will only contain Java examples. You'll have to adapt the code samples.
You'll need section 4.1.3 entitled "Signing a document using a smart card". You won't be able to use the code from 4.2 as it's specific to Java (because Java has a javax.smartcardio API). Your options are to use Windows-MY or PKCS#11.
Please don't expect to be able to copy/paste code and have it working without understanding what you're doing. See owlstead's remark.